# Alter toHtml() output in Varien form?

Tags: magento-1.7, forms

I bought an order attributes extension and as with all things Magento, I've been tweaking it to my tastes. They add in their `fieldset` of the new form elements into an existing checkout step. Their backend lets you pick what step and dynamically declare the extra attributes, too. I've already successfully changed three of the elements from simple text inputs to instead be `<SELECT>` dropdowns of attributes from our catalog.

Now I want to re-style the html so they go left to right and not in the generic order and layout of all Magento/Varien forms. I've done this dozens of times in various template `.phtml` files, but this case is defying my attempts.

My problem is that if I alter the template `fields.phtml` with my form (my usual practice), then the new order attributes show up on **every** checkout step, not just the one I want.

So I next think, ok, let's alter `_toHtml()` in `fields.php`. Now I have a chicken and egg problem in that this function starts off with calling `$html = parent::_toHtml();` which goes through the entire HTML building process.

The template file adds a bunch of stuff above my form, so it's not "easy" to just change the text string `$html`.

**Any ideas about getting hold of the `<SELECT>` html at some point in the chain?**

Their code flow is like this:
`Company/Extension/Block/Fields.php` `_toHtml()` calls `getFormElements()`, which instantiates a `new Varien_Data_Form()` and then creates the `fieldset` adding their attributes to the form with 
`$fieldset->addField($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $fieldType, $elementOptions)
                                    ->setEntityAttribute($attribute);`

At no point is there *any* raw HTML in their code for making these input fields.

`_toHtml()` then executes:
`$html = parent::_toHtml();`

which goes to: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php` which executes this series of calls:

▄ `_toHtml()` calls `renderView()`
▄ `renderView()` calls `$this->fetchView($this->getTemplateFile())`
▄ `fetchView()` simply does an `include()` of the template file, `fields.phtml`
▄ The template file, fields.phtml then does `foreach ($this->getFormElements() as $element)` ... and then does `echo $element->toHtml();` but, there's only one "element", which is the fieldset itself. 
▄ Next stop *I think* is `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php` where its `toHtml()` calls `getHtml()`
▄ `getHtml()` then calls `getDefaultHtml()`
▄ `getDefaultHtml()` in file `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Fieldset.php` actually generates the HTML itself, adding in the `<div><h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"></h4>` I'm seeing just above the fieldset itself in the page source.
▄ The fieldset is rendered via $this->getElementHtml() which in Fieldset.php, then does the  and  tags and for the actual elements in the fieldset, it runs `$html.= $this->getChildrenHtml();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up scraping the `$html` text via php's DOM classes. It's crude but it handily accomplished what I was looking for, which is getting form elements after the initial `textarea` to NOT each have their own `<SPAN>`, which made the form too bulky for my tastes.

In case someone Google's their way here, the working code is below. Tomorrow, I should post another answer with how I did this same feat for ADMINHTML form that was equally obtuse.

```
//  This gets the entirety of the HTML sent to the browser from 
//  the template file and this extension.
$html = parent::_toHtml();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
//  found via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778110/change-innerhtml-of-a-php-domelement
//  http://www.keyvan.net/2010/07/javascript-like-innerhtml-access-in-php
//  I added after $this class definition
$dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'JSLikeHTMLElement');

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$selects = '';

// get the fieldset node..
$fsNode=$dom->getElementsByTagName('fieldset')->item(0);
$spans = $fsNode->getElementsByTagName('span');

$idx=1; // skip 1st span child...


for ( ; $idx < $spans->length; $idx++ ) {
    $selects .= '<div class="left" style="padding:2px">';
    $span = $spans->item($idx);
    $els = $span->childNodes;

    foreach( $els as $el )
        $selects .= $this->getInnerHtml($el);
    $selects .= "</div>\n";
}

//  MUST step backwards to remove spans, or $spans will reset
//  This for loop came from comments at php.net
//  http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390
for ($idx = $spans->length; --$idx >= 0; ) {
    $span = $spans->item($idx);
    if( $idx > 1 )
        $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
    if( $idx == 1 ) {
        // Remove this span's children
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument
        $els = $span->childNodes;
        for( $jdx=$els->length; --$jdx >=0;  ) {
            $item = $els->item($jdx);
            $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
        }
        $span->innerHTML=$selects;

        break;
    }
}
$newHtml = '';
//  get rid of top level tags: <HEAD> etc. This exact code chosen
//  by observing the output of $dom->saveHTML();
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0)->childNodes as $node )
    $newHtml .= $this->getInnerHTML($node);

$html = $newHtml;

//  Probably from php.net:
function getInnerHTML($Node) {
    $Document = new DOMDocument();
    $Document->appendChild($Document->importNode($Node,true));
    return $Document->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: You can mark this answer as solution